# Call to a member function on null ZF2 Doctrine ORM 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

```
$section =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Section', $sectionId );
$class   =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Classes', $section->getClassId() );
$cycle   =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Cycle', $class->getCycleId() );
$branch  =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Branch', $cycle->getBranchId() );
$sectionArr = $class->getClassName()." ".$section->getSectionName()." - ". $branch->getBranchName()." ".$cycle->getCycleName();

$objectManager->close();
```

I am getting  `Call to a member function getCycleId() on null`, although if I `print_r($variable);exit;` after each variable I obtain a result up until the end, only when I remove it it gives me the error. What can be the solution?

Comment: Maybe, you execute this multiple times and the `exit()` will stop the script before the error occur. Add a `if ($class === null) {/* add debug info here*/ die();}` after the `$class = $objectManager->find[...]`.

Comment: it is crashing, but if I do print_r( $class);exit; instead, I get a result normally

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it with something like:

```
$section =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Section', $sectionId );
$class   =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Classes', $section->getClassId() );

if ($class === null) {
    /* add debug info here*/ 
    var_dump('ID of class was '.$section->getClassId());
    var_dump('ID of section was '.$sectionId);

    var_dump((new \Exception())->getTraceAsString());

    die();
}

$cycle   =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Cycle', $class->getCycleId() );
$branch  =  $objectManager->find('OEC\Entity\Branch', $cycle->getBranchId() );
$sectionArr = $class->getClassName()." ".$section->getSectionName()." - ". $branch->getBranchName()." ".$cycle->getCycleName();

$objectManager->close();
```

Like I said in my comment, maybe the code is runnig multiple times.

Comment: I have edited my response with more debug information. With that, you can get the IDs of the object that cause the trouble and solve it ;)